# Erro add-Migration .net core 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc, postgresql, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core-web-api

Estou tentando adicionar o add-migration na minha solução mas sempre acontece o seguinte erro "Value cannot be null (Parameter 'connectionString')"

mas minha string de conexao está correta no appsettings.json
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
  public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddMvc();
    services.AddDbContext<SimCoContext>(optBuilder =>
        optBuilder.UseNpgsql(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
}
```

`Appsettings.json`

```
{
  "ConnectionsStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "Host=localhost;Port=5432;Pooling=true;User ID=postgres;Password=admin;Database=SimCo;"
  },
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Warning",
      "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*"
}
```

Comment: Opte por colocar o código ao invés da imagem quando for colocar código.
Acredito que esteja escrito errado na linha 2 o ConnectionString

Comment: Provavelmente seu erro está na classe Startup onde você indica a string de conexão no método configure service você deve indicar "DefaultConnection".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Já verificou seu appsetting.Development.json?

Por padrão, quando o ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT não está definido nas suas variáveis de ambiente, ele usa a configuração Development.

Mais em: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/environments?view=aspnetcore-3.1

Answer (score 0):

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddMvc();
    services.AddDbContext<SimCoContext>(optBuilder =>
        optBuilder.UseNpgsql(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
}
```

`Appsettings.json`

```
{
  "ConnectionsStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "Host=localhost;Port=5432;Pooling=true;User ID=postgres;Password=admin;Database=SimCo;"
  },
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Warning",
      "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*"
}
```

Comment: Coloque isso na pergunta, aqui são as respostas ...